# Синтаксис XPATH для Postgre

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

Недавно начал изучать PostgreSQL, И наткнулся на функцию XPATH. Пытался найти информацию по поводу синтаксиса для первого параметра функции XPATH, как допустим в SQL  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp, однако найти не смог. Уверен что синтаксис должен отличаться, т.к. аналог MSSQl запросов:

```
XML.query('.')
XML.value('.','varchar(100)')
```

в PostgreSQL выглядит примерно так:

```
xpath('*',XML);
xpath('.',XML);
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING

Comment: Данная документация показывает сам функционал xpath как функции в PostgreSql. Там говориться про XPATH 1.0 expression, однако на практике код не делает то что написано по документации по XPATH 1.0 expression.

Comment: Я хрен знает - но fiddle показывает, что примеры из документации дают именно тот результат, который показан. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c089f3ba58890c3a68ad8b4b274c7e2d Так что написанному там всё же можно верить.

Comment: я же не говорю, что всё там не верно. Допустим в XPATH 1.0 expression говориться что при выборе '..' для пути должен выбираться родитель node-a однако так не делается. Может я просто не правильно понял документации или что?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b1f525ca2a03284687d1962356b215d1

Comment: Внутренний xpath даёт `<b><tuca><t_doc><param>1</param></t_doc><t_doc>2</t_doc><des><t_doc><param>3</param></t_doc><t_doc>4</t_doc></des></tuca></b>`. Что ты хочешь получить, запрашивая родителя у этого значения? Обрати внимание - это полученное значение уже не знает, что у него когда-то был родитель `<a>`.

Comment: Я хотел получить `<a><b><tuca><t_doc><param>1</param></t_doc><t_doc>2</t_doc><des><t_doc><param>3</param></t_doc><t_doc>4</t_doc></des></tuca></b></a>`, но если ты говоришь что файл полученный из xpath уже не знает своего родителя, то тогда понятно, почему не работает.

Comment: Конечно, внешний вызов xpath получает только значение, полученное при выполнении внутреннего. И не получает его истории. Как и для любых иных вложенных функций.

Comment: Тогда появляется вопрос, зачем нужен такой вариант поиска родителя, если при получении данных файл не имеет информации о своём родителе?

Comment: Скорее всего речь идёт о шаблонном выборе - ну грубо говоря во всём дереве найти узел с заданным именем (неизвестно в какой ветке и на каком уровне вложенности) и взять его родителя. Тогда это имеет смысл (но не для данной функции, которая не поддерживает шаблоны). PS. В XML не силён...